# iOS return one digit fragment from NSString

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, substring

I can't find an easy way to generate a one digit sized substring from an NSString. The NSString looks like "(N3)" but I need to store just the number portion "3" in an substring. Using:

```
NSString *subString = [dis substringFromIndex:2];
```

returns "3)".

Any ideas?

Comment: Search for `substringWithRange:` in the documentation.

Comment: Or, if you need a **character** only: `characterAtIndex:`. Warning: returns `unichar`, not `char`.

Comment: Or, if you know about `substringFromIndex:`, you surely know about `substringToIndex:` as well, in which case you should be able to work out the logic like `subs = [[orig substringFromIndex:2] substringToIndex:1];`

Comment: (Or, generally speaking, read the [manual](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html).  That's what it's there for.)

Comment: Hello H2CO3, thanks for `substringWithRange` hint. This works for me.

Comment: @HotLicks I'm out of upvotes! Damn! **Damn!** ***DAMN!!!***

Answer (score 0):

Well, if the string is one digit and its position is invariant, you could just use:

```
int Foo(NSString * dis) {
 const unichar c = [dis characterAtIndex:2];
 assert(isdigit(c) && "not a number");
 return c - '0';
}
```